# File in emulated DVD image exists, until you try to run it

Tags: windows-11, file-not-found, virtual-drive

I don't even know where to begin with this one.  I guess I can illustrate my flabbergastedness with this screenshot:

[Operation failed successfully?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHjNF.png)

[I don't know what happened here -- this was run direct from the original disc and failed on the first try but then succeeded when I immediately tried again??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRIO5.png)

The disc is just a bunch of images from a whole battery of MRI scans I had last week.  The technology on the disc is old, maybe even ancient at this point.  I just want to view my results ahead of my neurology appointment tomorrow.  I also want to make sure the neurologist has the software to read this disc, if the hospital somehow screwed up the burn.  (BTW, no, there is no security or encryption on this disc -- I requested it directly from the MRI tech before it was even entered into my medical record.)

But, primarily, I still don't get how Windows is telling me the file it sees in the given directory does not exist when trying to run it.  I literally don't know where to begin.